# How many solutions $x_1+\dots+x_8=30$ has?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> Enumerate the solutions of
>   $$x_1+\dots+x_8=30$$
>   where $2\leq x_i\leq 5$ for $i=1,\dots,6$,
>   and $x_7$ and $x_8$ must be or 5 or 10.

I am not sure with my process. 
and I would like to ask you if you have a better way to solve this?
and if I am right.
$S_0 - S_1 + S_2 - S_3\dots$ etc. is the solution. 
but i think im doing something wrong:
[my solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcLED.jpg)

Comment: What are exactly the constraints?

Comment: sorry robert i didnt notice. i edit it

Comment: If this is the problem you asked me about, I would approach the problem in the same way that Robert Z did.  Are you having difficulty understanding the details of his calculations?

Answer (score 5):

A possible way is using generating functions:

- First set $y_i = x_i-2$ for $i=1,\ldots , 6$ and $y_i = x_i -5$ for $i=7,8$. So, you look for the number of solutions of 
  $$\mbox{}y_1 + \cdots + y_6 + y_7 + y_8 = 8 \mbox{ with } 0\leq y_i \leq 3 \;(i=1,\ldots ,6) \mbox{ and } y_i \in \{0,5\}\;(i=7,8)$$
- So you look for the coefficient of $x^8$ of the generating function of this problem (look at the exponents): $$(1+x+x^2+x^3)^6(1+x^5)^2 = \left(\frac{1-x^4}{1-x}\right)^6(1+x^5)^2$$
- Using $\frac{1}{(1-x)^6} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+5}{5}x^n$ (which can easily be verified by repeated differentiation), you get
  \begin{eqnarray*} [x^8]\left(\frac{1-x^4}{1-x}\right)^6(1+x^5)^2
  & = & [x^8](1-6x^4+\binom{6}{2}x^8)(1+2x^5)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+5}{5}x^n \\
  & = & [x^8](1-6x^4+2x^5 + \binom{6}{2}x^8)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+5}{5}x^n \\
  & = & \binom{8+5}{5} - 6\binom{4+5}{5} + 2\binom{3+5}{5} + \binom{6}{2}\\
  & = & \boxed{658}
  \end{eqnarray*}

Comment: (1+x+x2+x3)6 = ((1−x^4)/(1−x))^6 -> always? is that a rule?

Comment: Yes. This rule is called geometric sum formula: $1+x+ \cdots + x^n = \frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$.  So, in the context of such combinatoric problems this turns out to be a quite powerful tool.

Comment: amazing. thank you very much.  i like trance too. :D

Comment: @LORINECHERRY Yeah. Good choice. :-)

Comment: @LORINECHERRY : Btw., it is quite useful to check out that generating function stuff a bit. Because it can provide quite quick and fancy solutions to combinatorial problems where one would usually resort to stars-and-bars together with inclusion-exclusion which can be really nasty sometimes.

Comment: oh thanks. can you send me a link to all the useful ones? i have a discrete math exam at monday

Comment: What did you put in place of X? one line before the last @trancelocation

Comment: @LORINECHERRY Difficult to decide what appeals to you. There are plenty of web pages about generating functions and combinatorics. The following one contains a couple of examples in the paragraph "Counting Problems and Generating Functions": https://math.berkeley.edu/~shiyu/s15math53/generating_functions.pdf

Comment: I did not put in any $x$. I just collected all coefficients, which have an $x^8$ when multiplying the series with the $4$ expressions in the brackets. For example $-6x^4$ would match with $\binom{4+5}{5}x^4$ in the series to create an expression with $x^8$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99460/discussion-between-lorine-cherry-and-trancelocation).

Comment: @trancelocation (+1) I like g.f. This is the best way to do it. In my answer I tried to follow OP's approach.

Comment: +1. You can in fact skip the first step, making the second step looking for the coefficient of $x^{30}$ in $(x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5)^6(x^5+x^{10})^2 = x^{22}\left(\frac{1-x^4}{1-x}\right)^6(1+x^5)^2$ and this takes you to the third step

Answer (score 1):

I will try to follow the approach given in your solution in a correct way.

Let $y_i=x_i-2$ for $i=1,\dots,6$ with $0\leq y_i\leq 3$. We consider three cases.

i) If $x_7=x_8=5$ then the equation $x_1+\dots+x_8=30$ can be written as
$$y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4+y_5+y_6=30-x_7-x_8-2\cdot 6=8.$$

ii) If $x_7=5,x_8=10$ or $x_7=10,x_8=5$ then the equation $x_1+\dots+x_8=30$ can be written as
$$y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4+y_5+y_6=30-x_7-x_8-2\cdot 6=3.$$

iii) If $x_7=x_8=10$ then the equation $x_1+\dots+x_8=30$ can be written as
$$y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4+y_5+y_6=30-x_7-x_8-2\cdot 6=-2.$$

In each case we use the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) and we apply [Stars-and-Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)#Theorem_two).

For i), let $S_k$ be the number of solutions with at least $k$ terms $y_i\geq 4$, then 
$$\begin{align}
n_1&=S_0-S_1+S_2= \binom{8+5}{5}-6\binom{(8-4)+5}{5}+\binom{6}{2}\binom{(8-4-4)+5}{5}\\
&=1287-6\cdot126 +15 \cdot 1=546.
\end{align}$$
For ii),
$$n_2=2\cdot S_0= 2\cdot\binom{3+5}{5}=2\cdot 56=112.$$
The last case iii) is trivial and we have $n_3=0$.
Hence the final result is 
$$n_1+n_2+n_3=546+112+0=\boxed{658}.$$

Comment: unfortunately i am not fully understand, If you took 2 down from the normal x and call it y now, why you summarize six times y without the X7 and X8? im confused

Comment: @LORINECHERRY We have $6$ ways to choose one $y_k\geq 4$ with $k=1,...,6$.
We have $\binom{6}{2}$ ways to choose two distinct $y_k\geq 4$ with $k=1,...,6$.
$x_7$ and $x_8$ are fixed in each case. See my edit.

Comment: @LORINECHERRY Let me know if you have further doubts. I tried to use your approach in a correct way. Is it helpful?

Comment: YESSSS THANKS! @robert Z

Comment: @RobertZ The OP may come back to you as Lorine had never seen g.f. before. Anyways (+1) for the cumbersome way according to OP's approach :-).

Comment: @LORINECHERRY Then, may I know what are your doubts here?